# SQL - Restrict the number of rows returned based on a count of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is what my data looks like:

```
item_ID | group_ID | count_of_items_in_group

2|ABC|3

5|ABC|3

9|ABC|3

29|DEF|3

3|DEF|3

4|DEF|3

200|XYZ|2

300|XYZ|2

600|GHI|1
```

**SQL Filddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfe09/1

For each group, I want to limit the number of item_IDs returned to a max of 2. I do not care which 2 are returned. If the group has less than 2 rows return only the 1 row.

I can't write a select top * 2 for each group and union the selects because I have a few hundred groups.

I'm not sure where to start, your help is greatly appreciated.

Using MS SQL 2005

(Table layout is exactly as it is in the sample, it is a view based on a number of queries)

Comment: BTW pretty good question, a real good question, and posting a SQL fiddle is faster for us to help you with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using  [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)  to enum the number of fields of your data set, partitioned by each group_id.

And after that just return when is just less or equal to 2?  or any number that you want

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  select item_id, group_id, count_of_items, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY count_of_items DESC) 
  AS RN
  from items_in_groups
) A
WHERE RN <= 2
```

Here is the [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfe09/17)

Comment: Please paste solution from fiddle here.  Good work by the way!

Comment: Works a treat. I'm marking yours as correct since you posted before Goat CO. Thank you. BTW, this SQL Fiddle thing is amazing, didn't know it existed until yesterday !

Comment: glad we helped you! And yes pretty amazing tool, also available for JQuery & HTML if it helps you someday :)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY item_id) as RowRank 
      from items_in_groups
      )sub
WHERE RowRank <=2
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfe09/13/0)

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY group_id`  then for each unique `group_id` value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: I'm not sure this will actually work. `ROW_NUMBER` wasn't implemented until 2008 right?

Answer (score 1):

Can do this as a min and a max select statement, union them together and group by to eliminate any duplicates that one row groups would provide

```
 select item_id, group_id
from(
(select max(item_id) as item_id, group_id from table group by group_id) a
 union all
(select min(item_id) as item_id, group_id from table group by group_id) b) qry
group by item_id,group_id
```

Not the prettiest I'm sure, but it works.  It's usually best to have some type of logic built in, not "I do not care which 2 are returned."

(Edit - I put the groupID in the groupo by and not item_ID.   Ha, silly mistake I'll blame on dyslexia.  Corrected now)

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, using `union` instead of `union all` would eliminate the duplicates, it joins only new rows, so you can get rid of the `group by` for a better performance of the query