# Restricting the number of rows selected from a view

Tags: view, permissions, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to create a view in SQL Server 2012 such that no matter what query is run against it, it only returns a fixed number of records?

The use case is that I want to expose a view to users, but I don't want them to go pulling inordinately large sets of data from the view.

Comment: No, the view **definition** cannot specify anything like that. It's up to the consumer of the view to make sure he doesn't select too many rows...

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create the view itself to have top operator

```
select top 100 * from ------------
```

Comment: Not quite. Let's say the view can return 10,000,000 records, 9,999,000 which have an Origin field whose value is 'Nkala' and 1,000 whose Origin value is 'Nkolo'. Now if I use 'SELECT TOP 1000 * ...' in my view, and if I write a query based on the view which filters out records from it - like SELECT * FROM  WHERE Origin = 'Nkolo' - I will get much less than the 1,000 'Nkolo' records I have should got from the view. This is because the view will bring the first 1,000 records back (which will likely not be all 'Nkolo' records), and when I filter on that, I'll not get up to 1,000 'Nkolo' records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER ( )` to ristrict the number of records from the database

for more details you can also visit these questions

- [SQL - Restrict the number of rows returned based on a count of
  rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856197/sql-restrict-the-number-of-rows-returned-based-on-a-count-of-rows)