# SQL Server: How to select fist 10 records from table without using TOP keyword

Tags: sql-server

There is a table which contains 50 records. I want to select first 10 records without using TOP keyword.

Comment: What defines the first 10 records?  you could order by and use rowNum <=10.  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856197/sql-restrict-the-number-of-rows-returned-based-on-a-count-of-rows

Comment: Is there a reason why `TOP` cannot be used?

Comment: Is this an interview question? Sounds quite strange that you wouldn't use top...

Comment: Why is this question getting so much downvote? Just trying to better understand the meta.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use [`OFFSET ... FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable
ORDER BY YourColumn ASC 
OFFSET  0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and `Common Table Expression` to query any range of data.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
( 
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, RowNumber  
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber <= 10  -- other conditions: RowNumber between 50 and 60
```

Refere [ROW NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) Here

Comment: I have done this now:Select * from 
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by category_id) as 'Row_Number', * 
    from category_master
) as tbl
Where tbl.Row_Number <= 5

Answer (score 1):

Although it's probably the same thing internally, you can use

> set rowcount 10

and then run the query.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try something like this:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Name FROM Table t
WHERE 10 > (SELECT count(*) FROM Table t2 WHERE t.id > t2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). Let's say your table contains columns `ID` and `Name`. In that case you can use such query:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Name
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber
    FROM TableName
) t
WHERE RowNumber <= 10
```